# Adding search bar to a blogdown website

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

I am considering using `blogdown` as a notebook, but missing in most of the templates is the ability to search through your tags, titles, or text. Is it possible to add a search bar in `blogdown` similar to `bookdown`?

I've read that you can use `lunr.js` to create static search functionality (like `bookdown`, but I didn't find it straightforward to do so or any tutorials that explained the steps needed to get it to work.

Comment: FYI here is the official Hugo doc: https://gohugo.io/tools/search/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with bookdown, but I use the [Beautiful Hugo](https://github.com/halogenica/beautifulhugo) theme for my blowdown website and I was easily able to add a google custom search bar that searches my site for tags, text, and titles.

In the config.toml file for this theme there is a place to enter your "gcse" which stands for google custom search engine. If I remember correctly all I had to do was go to google.com/cse, get my code, and then plug it into the config.toml file. You also have to make sure to go to "Look and Feel" and change Layout to "Full Width" and Theme to "Classic" in the setup once you've gotten your code from google.com/cse.

If you go to [my site](https://jennadallen.com) and click the search icon in the upper right hand corner of the page, you can see if it does what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd really like to do that with the Huge academic theme.